# How to place two elements next to each other inside flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place two elements inside div flexbox next to each other.

What I'm trying to do?

I have a side drawer flexbox within that i have list items. each list item has div flexbox which contains svg, span element and timestamp

I want this svg and span element and timestamp to stay in same line
if the span content exceeds the width it should move to next line without pushing the timestamp to next line.

[image]

So each list item should be like in above picture...

Below is the code,

```
<div class="drawer">
    <header>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="list_item">
                <div class="details">
                    <svg>
                    <span>somettttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
                </div>
                <timestamp/>
             </div>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>

.drawer {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     position: absolute;
     width: 320px;
     top: 55px;
     right: 18px;
     min-height: 40%;
     max-height: 80%;
     overflow: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;


     header {
         min-height: 38px;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: space-between;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-top: 2px;
    }}


.list_item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px;

    svg {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }

   .details {
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-items: center;

   }}
```

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that flex properties work on the direct flex children only:

- you can make your `details` div also a flexbox (maybe you can remove `align-items: center` from your flexboxes like below)
- add `break-word: break-all` to the `span` to break the text if not enough space in one line
- optionally you can have `flex: 0 0 auto` on the `svg` to preserve the *auto* dimensions of the svg

See a simplified demo below:

```css
.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  top: 55px;
  right: 18px;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  min-height: 38px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.list_item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  padding: 4px;
}

svg {
  margin-right: 6px;
  background: aliceblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto; /* take auto width, don't shrink or grow */
}

.details {
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*align-items: center;*/
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.details span {
  word-break: break-all; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <header></header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="list_item">
        <div class="details">
          <svg height="20" width="50">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">SVG</text>
</svg>
          <span>sometttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </div>
        <div>00:00</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list_item">
        <div class="details">
          <svg height="20" width="50">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">SVG</text>
</svg>
          <span>somettttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </div>
        <div>00:00</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list_item">
        <div class="details">
          <svg height="20" width="50">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">SVG</text>
</svg>
          <span>somettttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </div>
        <div>00:00</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the timestamp moves to next line...example timestamp "2019-04-03T04:53:39.368106+00:00"

Comment: okay i have added flex: 0 0 auto; to timestamp as well and works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for your items too. then make it justify-content:flex-start and give a margin-left: auto to the timestamp.

```css
.item{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  border: 1px solid #888888;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding : 4px;
  width: 200px;
  
}
.item .time{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.item .icon{
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}
.item p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ipsum ipsum</p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
  <div class="item">
  <span class="icon">&#x2665;</span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
  <span class="time">12:45</span>
</div>
</div>
```